# Why does my entry language selection look different from examples?

Tags: localization, entry

All the examples look like this:

[image: Documentation and Examples]

Mine looks like the image below where you have to select the site from that top left dropdown and then there are some enabled things on the right:

[image: Mine]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top screenshot is from Craft 2. The entry language selector (technically, the entry *site* selector since Craft 3) was redesigned with Craft 3.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to change "Enabled for site" to say something else?

Comment: You can set a static translation for it https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/static-translations.html